# How can I access elastic beanstalk environment properties in docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to create environment variable in docker so that I can keep sensitive
information for configuration of production .
I am trying to get environment variable in docker by environment properties which is located in the configuration of  beanstalk  **modify** of the **Software** card . But I can't access environment variable by this .
How can I access environment variable from environment properties in **EB** for **docker**

Comment: Do you need the ENV variables in the Dockerfile or in the running app? Because I have many EB Docker apps up, and they can access the ENV variables set in the eb GUI/CLI.

Comment: If this is about the Dockerfile and build process, then the issue is that EB doesn't build containers, that needs to happen on a server somewhere else